# Stormpath User information

Tags: node.js, express, stormpath

ok this is my router code and I am trying to access user account information when they are on the home page. So far no luck... what am I doing wrong here?

```
// Render the dashboard page.
router.get('/home', function (req, res) {
  if (!req.user || req.user.status !== 'ENABLED') {
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }



  console.log('User:', req.user.email, 'just accessed the /home page!');


  //user: req.user

  res.render('home', {
    title: 'Home',
    user:req.user.username
    }

  );


});
```

Comment: Hi there.  Can you tell us which Stormpath repository you are working with, such as [stormpath-express-sample](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express-sample) or [stormpath-express](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express) ?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, its stormpath express sample.

Answer (score 2):

the issue (it appears) is that you don't have the loginRequired middleware set on your route. You should modify your function signature to:

```
router.get('/home', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res) {
  ...
});
```

This will force the user to be evaluated correctly =)

Comment: well I dunno Users can only reach this area by logging in.. I just couldn't get stormpath to return any user data..

Comment: You have to have the loginRequired stuff in order for the stormpath library to retrieve the user details for that route.

Comment: Wanna post all your app code? You could also email it to me if you want: randall@stormpath.com

Answer (score 1):

Your example looks correct, though I would assign the entire user object in the render call (right now you're just passing the username).

So if you placed this in `routes/index.js`

```
// Render the 'home' page if logged in and account is not disabled
router.get('/home', function (req, res) {
  if (!req.user || req.user.status !== 'ENABLED') {
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }

  res.render('home', {
    title: 'Home',
    user: req.user
  });

});
```

Then the view in `views/home.jade` would look like this:

```
html
  head
    title=title
  body
    p Hello, #{user.username}
```

Comment: could you just give me an example that uses `router.get('/home', function (req, res) { ` and the user object please. there must be something small I am missing...

Comment: You can access the username directly with `res.locals.user.username`

Comment: so  your `code` example is this placed in the `app.js` file? Because I had placed my original code in `routes >> index.js`

Comment: Ah!  My bad, I was showing an example for stormpath-express, not stormpath-express-sample.  I've updated this answer accordingly.

Comment: So CustomData. I was following the same principle and can see my custom data when logged... but rendering it using jade like the others isn't going to plan. This is what I have: `res.render('home', {
    title: 'Home',
    user: req.user,
    cD: req.user.customData,
  });`

Comment: I then called it using `p Hello, #{cd.item1}`

Comment: Have you enabled automatic expansion for custom data?  See http://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/product.html#automatic-expansion

Comment: yep. `var strategy = new StormpathStrategy({
    expansions: 'customData'
});` as I mentioned I can see my customData in the terminal but I can't get it to render to screen.